# Django - ask user for menuitem choices on each menu item

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am developing a simple restaurant app in django and mysql and after days of googling and research, i wasn't able to find a suitable answere for this particular problem, here is my django Model

```
class MenuItem(models.Model):

menu_category       = models.ForeignKey(MenuCategory, to_field='slug', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name                = models.CharField(max_length=30)
image               = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/menu/')
slug                = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
price               = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=0)
created_at          = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at          = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

and here is the problem:
for example i have a menuItem "MEXICAN BURGER" i would like to ask the user their choice of meat.. ie either chicken or beef, or their choice of bread, white or brown,

or i might be having a MenuItem "OMELETTE COMBO" and i would like to ask the user the type of omellete they'd like to have eg  ('spanish omelete', 'spinach and mushroom omelete')

or i might be having a MenuItem "ESPRESSO" and i would like them to choose between ('single', 'double')

*one menuitem can have multitple choices related to it, ie burger item can have choice of bread as well as choice of meat
for a better understanding of my problem visit this
[link](https://cafejavas.co.ug/user/productDetails/MTAyNg==?cat=BIG%20ON%20BREAKFAST&subcat=BREAKFAST%20COMBOS)
*
and this [another link](https://cafejavas.co.ug/user/productDetails/MzAz?cat=GENEROUS%20BIG%20MEALS&subcat=STARTERS%20AND%20APPETIZERS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another model as needed e.g. `MeatOption` and add to it a ForeignKey to MenuItem:

```
class MeatOption(models.Model):
    meat_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class MenuItem(models.Model):
    meat_type = models.ForeignKey(MeatOption, null=True, blank=True)
    # rest of fields
```

Ideally you should think  of categorizing your items and reflect that categorization into your models. i.e. you could have class Burgers, class Beverages and so on, so that you only include the relevant options.

And if there is common functionality among all those categories you could inherit that from a Base MenuItem class like so:

```
class MenuItem(models.Model):
    # common fields across all items go here

class Burger(MenuItem):
    # burger-specific fields here
    meat_type = models.ForeignKey(MeatOption)

class Omelette(MenuItem):
    # omelette-specific fields here
    ingredient = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)

 class Ingredient(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

the details depend on your use-case of course

Comment: you said "categorization into your models. i.e. you could have class Burgers, class Beverages" but that isn't a solution becuase i want it to be dynamic. i.e the system administrator should be able to add these choices and therefore the user can be asked for their chocies

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions to this.

### Code Based: Inheritance

You create Mixins for each of your choice type and subclass MenuItem and these mixins.

```
from django.db.models import CharField, TextChoices, Model

class MeatChoices(TextChoices):
    CHICKEN = 'chi'
    BEEF = 'bee'

class MeatMixin(Model):
    meat_choices = CharField(max_length=3, choices=MeatChoices.choices, default=MeatChoices.CHICKEN)

class MeatMenuItem(MeatMixin, MenuItem):
    pass
```

This will require code changes whenever more choices are added to the menu or the menu is changed in that matter.

### Data Based: Generic Models

To allow the admin user to create and add choices to the menu items via the Django Admin, you need to create a model structure that enables specifying choices:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db.models import ManyToManyField, CharField, Model

class Ingredient(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class IngredientChoiceGroup(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    # simple solution for postgres only:
    # ingredients = ArrayField(CharField(max_length=50))
    # if not postgres or you need more attributes to ingredient:
    ingredients = ManyToManyField(Ingredient)


class MenuItem(models.Model):
    
    menu_category       = models.ForeignKey(MenuCategory, to_field='slug', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name                = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    image               = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/menu/')
    slug                = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    price               = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=0)
    created_at          = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at          = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    ingredient_choices = ManyToManyField(IngredientChoiceGroup)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This method would allow to configure multiple choice groups per menu item, e.g. "BREAD" and "MEAT". And you can do that all via the Django Admin.

You might need to work out the details. This is just a draft.

Note about `ArrayField`: it is a simpler structure in the DB, but for the Admin you will need to add a specific widget via 3rd party library or at least write your own parser. In the end, M2M field might be the better choice.

Comment: how would the mixins work? becuase remember it has to be dynamic. the admin user should be able to add these choices for example choices for burgers.. would be choice of bread and choice of meat.. the admin should be able to add any other choice to the menuitem and the user will be asked for it

Comment: could you explain more on "Generic Models"

Comment: for better understanding of the issue. please visit this link 
https://cafejavas.co.ug/user/productDetails/MzAz?cat=GENEROUS%20BIG%20MEALS&subcat=STARTERS%20AND%20APPETIZERS

Comment: If you need the Admin to add the choices then you cannot make it work with the Mixins. You should have said so in your question. "Generic Models" is just a term I chose to name the generic solution. "Generic" means that it is a general, extendable solution.

Comment: could you please have a look at those links i sent you.